# How to avoid a dialog box for input (e.g. "Open File" behavior)?

Tags: find-file, gtk3, inputs

I generally like to use the emacs-gtk3 package for my editing since I find it has better compatibility with my clipboard and a couple packages I use..but I don't like opening files in the GUI version of emacs. I like how I can open a file from the nox version and I can type the path to the file. I find it much more efficient. Is there a setting to prevent Emacs from using the GUI file manager and instead use the one that shows up at the bottom bar? I can't find an answer in any of my searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe this is it.

If option `use-dialog-box` is non-`nil`, and if you use the mouse to invoke a command that asks you for some input such as a file name, then Emacs pops up a dialog box for you to choose the input (e.g. the file name).

If you customize that option to `nil` then Emacs just prompts you in the minibuffer, and you type the input (e.g. the file name), typically with completion.

`C-h v use-dialog-box` tells you:

> **`use-dialog-box`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>   Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means mouse commands use dialog boxes to ask questions.
>
> This applies to `y-or-n-p` and `yes-or-no-p` questions asked by commands
>   invoked by mouse clicks and mouse menu items.
>
> On some platforms, file selection dialogs are also enabled if this is
>   non-`nil`.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 21.1 of Emacs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. My "Emacs vocabulary" is very poor so I apologize for the confusion, but thank you so much for pointing that out to me!